# Fortran operator overloading with generic function

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, gfortran

I would like to use the generic name of a function to overload the '*' operator as in the example below:

```
interface scala
    module procedure :: scalapr,scalarp
end interface scala
interface operator(*)
   module procedure :: scala
end interface operator(*)
```

However, compiling with gfortran, I get:

```
Error: Procedure 'scala' in intrinsic '*' operator at (1) is neither function nor subroutine
```

Is there any turn-around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must overload with the specific function

```
interface scala
    module procedure :: scalapr,scalarp
end interface scala
interface operator(*)
   module procedure :: scalapr, scalarp
end interface operator(*)
```

The generic is not a module procedure, so it cannot appear in `module procedure`.

There is also just `procedure`, but that won't help here. It is for procedures not coming form the current module. But anyway, the functions in the generic interface block **must** be specific functions.

See Fortran 2008 `12.4.3.4 Generic interfaces`:

> 1 A generic interface block specifies a generic interface for each of
>   the procedures in the interface block. The PROCEDURE statement lists
>   **procedure pointers, external procedures, dummy procedures, or module
>   procedures** that have this generic interface. ...

According to 7.1.6:

```
5 A function defines the binary operation x1 op x2 if
  (2) either
     (a)  a generic interface (12.4.3.2) provides the function with a generic-spec of OPERATOR (op),
  or
     (b)  there is a generic binding (4.5.5) in the declared type
```

so the rules above do apply as does the constraint

> C1207 (R1206) A procedure-name shall be a nonintrinsic procedure that
>   has an explicit interface.

A *generic-name* does not conform to C1207.

Comment: That was clear from the compiler message. My question was if there is any alternative.

Comment: Nope, there isn't. That's what I am saying. (You would be surprised how many people here don't read or don't try to understand compiler messages.)